# Signing out of Xcode Organizer?

Tags: xcode

I've got multiple developer accounts setup on my Mac, and now needs to sign out of my account to access another's resources. I couldn't find such option anywhere.

Any idea how to sign out of Xcode Organizer?

Comment: The current account is iOS only, while the another is Mac+iOS, and I need to download the Command line tools using the latter's credentials.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Open **Keychain Access**, go to the **Passwords** category and remove the passwords associated with **Xcode**. Their name contains **apple.com** (example: **daw2.apple.com**).

If you have a doubt about whether a password is associated with **Xcode**, right click on it, select **Get Info** and see if **Xcode** is listed in the **Access Control** tab.

Finally, note that **Xcode** asks you if you want to save the passwords in **Keychain** when you enter them. You can skip saving them so that you can choose the correct account every time.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Additionally, the new login dialog didn't show up for me until I went the the Devices tab in Organizer and hit the refresh button at bottom right.

Comment: surprisingly Apple does not have a Logout button in xCode .

Answer (score 3):

In the latest xcode (v9.2) I had to goto xcode (in the menu bar), then preferences, then click on the 'accounts' tab. Here I could remove the old account.

Comment: this one works in 2023